# Rails form using a jQuery star selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails form that I am using to create a testimonial.
Currently I am using a form number_field to select a star rating from 1 to 5.

I have a jQuery star selector that I would like to use on the form, but am unsure of how to save the data-value as the star rating when submitting the form.
Is there a way of doing this?

**form**

```
<h1>Comment as <%= current_user.first_name %> <%= current_user.last_name %></h1>
<div class="border border-grey-light rounded" style ="padding: 10px;">
  <%= image_tag current_user.avatar_thumbnail, class: "avatar", alt: "avatar" %>
  <%= form_with model: @testomonial do |f| %>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <%= f.label :review, class: "label" %>
      <%= f.text_field :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write review in here" %>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <%= f.label :stars, class: "label" %>
      <%= f.number_field :star, in: 1..5, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary text-base py-1.5 px-5", value: "Post testomonial" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**star rating selector**

```
<div class='rating-stars text-center'>
  <ul id='stars'>
    <li class='star' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
      <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
    </li>
    <li class='star' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
      <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
    </li>
    <li class='star' title='Good' data-value='3'>
      <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
    </li>
    <li class='star' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
      <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
    </li>
    <li class='star' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
      <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery for the star selector**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  /* 1. Visualizing things on Hover - See next part for action on click */
  $('#stars li').on('mouseover', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently mouse on

    // Now highlight all the stars that's not after the current hovered star
    $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e){
      if (e < onStar) {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      }
      else {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
      }
    });

  }).on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e){
      $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
  });


  /* 2. Action to perform on click */
  $('#stars li').on('click', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently selected
    var stars = $(this).parent().children('li.star');

    for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).removeClass('selected');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < onStar; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).addClass('selected');
    }

    // JUST RESPONSE (Not needed)
    var ratingValue = parseInt($('#stars li.selected').last().data('value'), 10);
    var msg = "";
    if (ratingValue > 1) {
        msg = "Thanks! You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
    }
    else {
        msg = "We will improve ourselves. You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
    }
    responseMessage(msg);

  });


});
```

**Edited form - working**

```
<%= form_with model: @testomonial do |f| %>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= f.label :review, class: "label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write review in here" %>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= f.label :stars, class: "label" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :star %>
    <!-- star selector: -->
    <div class='rating-stars text-center'>
      <ul id='stars'>
        <li class='star' data-value='1'>
          <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
        </li>
        <li class='star' data-value='2'>
          <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
        </li>
        <li class='star' data-value='3'>
          <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
        </li>
        <li class='star' data-value='4'>
          <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
        </li>
        <li class='star' data-value='5'>
          <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary text-base py-1.5 px-5", value: "Post testomonial" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**edited jQuery with star selector inputting value to form - working**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* 1. Visualizing things on Hover - See next part for action on click */
  $('#stars li').on('mouseover', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently mouse on

    // Now highlight all the stars that's not after the current hovered star
    $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e){
      if (e < onStar) {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      }
      else {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
      }
    });

  }).on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e){
      $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
  });
  /* 2. Action to perform on click */
  $('#stars li').on('click', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently selected
    var stars = $(this).parent().children('li.star');

    for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).removeClass('selected');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < onStar; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).addClass('selected');
    }

    // JUST RESPONSE (Not needed)
    var ratingValue = parseInt($('#stars li.selected').last().data('value'), 10);
    $("#testomonial_star").val(ratingValue);
  });
});
function responseMessage(msg) {
  $('.success-box').fadeIn(200);
  $('.success-box div.text-message').html("<span>" + msg + "</span>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the star value to the input when the user clicks on the mouse - rails will create an id for your input inside your form which I suppose in your case would be `testomonial_star`

```js
/* 2. Action to perform on click */
  $('#stars li').on('click', function(){
    ... same code here

    // JUST RESPONSE (Not needed)
    var ratingValue = parseInt($('#stars li.selected').last().data('value'), 10);
    //Add rating to the form
    $("#testomonial_star").val(ratingValue)

    ... same code here

  });
```

I would set the star input as hidden `<%= f.hidden_field :star %>` since you already have a view for the stars rating

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. I added the modified form and jQuery to the question. Thanks again